# save result of search and replace feature PowerGREP

Tags: powergrep

I want to save result of search and replace feature of PowerGREP to excel or csv file that contains separate column for replaced by, full file name and what is replaced.

Can anyone help on this ?

I know we can export result (as text file) but that's not what I need.

Comment: Pipe or redirect the output, depending on how you're calling `grep` and whatever best suits your needs?  Can you show how you're performing the function call?  If you've tried to do any storing of the results so far, please show that as well.  Finally, if this isn't being done through a script or programming language call, it might be better to [ask this elsewhere](http://www.superuser.com), since it wouldn't really be about programming.

Comment: @gravity - Please find https://www.powergrep.com/screen.html section Search and replace. There is a result tab with colored. I want that result as separate file having replaced by, full file name and what is replaced values.